# R. huge vector of 2 character strings

Tags: r, string, vector

In order to label thousands of random points I need a huge vector with labels. For logistic reasons I would like that all strings has length 2. What I have so far is this string

```
sl = paste(letters[1],letters,":0",sep="")
for (i in 2:26){
  ll = paste(letters[i],letters,":0",sep="")
  sl = c(sl,ll)
}
SL = paste(LETTERS[1],LETTERS,":0",sep="") 
for (i in 2:26){
  ll = paste(LETTERS[i],LETTERS,":0",sep="")
  SL = c(SL,ll)
}
S1 = paste(LETTERS[1],0:9,":0",sep="")
for (i in 2:26){
  ll = paste(LETTERS[i],1:10,":0",sep="")
  SL = c(SL,ll)
}
s1 = paste(letters[1],0:9,":0",sep="")
for (i in 2:26){
  ll = paste(letters[i],1:10,":0",sep="")
  SL = c(SL,ll) 
}
sl=c(sl,SL,S1,s1)
```

this vector has 1872 strings only. Taking in account that my questions are

1. Do you know a more elegant way to have something like this? I am building a package and I find this lines not elegant at all.
2. Do you know how can I easily increase the length of the vector with more normal strings of length 2?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "In order to label thousands of random points" Do you plot them on a house wall? I don't see any sense in this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Limiting yourself to two character strings and including all permutations of `c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9)` gives you a maximum of `62^2 = 3844` possibilities.  That full vector can be generated via

```
paste0(
  as.vector(
    outer(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9),
          c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9),
          paste0)
  ),
  ":0"
)
```

If you need more labels than that, you will need to either include more characters to select from, or increase the length of the string.

However, I think such a labeling scheme may not be as useful as you hope.  Labeling points like this on a plot runs the risk of making the plot unreadable.  Are you sure this is the approach you need?